# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol

Tags: plsql

i am trying to compile this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_error_msg (err_num PLS_INTEGER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
BEGIN 
RETURN sqlerrm(-err_num); 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
RETURN NULL; 
END sql_error_msg
/
```

but i am getting this error:

```
FUNCTION SQL_ERROR_MSG
On line:  8
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `;` at the end of the function.

```
 END sql_error_msg;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to execute PL/SQL that "creates or replaces" a function, using `<jdbc:initialize-database>` tag. I was given the PLS-00103 and it turned out PL/SQL is not currently supported this way.

You have to execute the script in a different way.

I am going to try directly with JDBC as per http://www.coderanch.com/t/298532/JDBC/databases/run-SQL-Script-file-JDBC
and work out a solutiom from there.